# Populating array is failing

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, google-maps

I am struggeling with an issue on my website. It is a website managed using WordPress as CMS. I created a custom post type containing a latitude and longitude value. I am running through the post and fetching the data right. However, when i try to save the posts in each array depending on the post category the dat population within the second array is failing. Please see the code below:

```
<div style="display: none;">

    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php $b = 1; ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php  $terms = get_the_terms($loop->ID, 'observationcat'); ?>

            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) {?>

               <?php if ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 112)) : ?>

                    <div id="itemFundet<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a>
                        <?php echo'<p>Kategori ID: ' . $term->term_id . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php echo'<p>Kategori: ' . $term->name . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <?php echo '<p>Tabt udstyr nummer: ' . $i . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true) ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php $i++; ?>

                <?php elseif ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 113)) : ?>

                    <div id="itemTabt<?php echo $b; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a>
                        <?php echo'<p>Kategori ID: ' . $term->term_id . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php echo'<p>Kategori: ' . $term->name . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <?php echo '<p>Fundet udstyr nummer: ' . $b . '</p>'; ?>
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true) ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php $b++; ?>  

                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
```

Page template - Javascript:

```
var locationsFundet = [

    <?php $i = 1; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) { ?>

            <?php if ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 112)) : ?>
            {
                latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true) ?>), 
                info : document.getElementById('itemFundet<?php echo $i; ?>')
            },

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php $i++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
];

var locationsTabt = [

    <?php $b = 1; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) { ?>

            <?php if ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 113)) : ?>
            {
                latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true) ?>), 
                info : document.getElementById('itemTabt<?php echo $b; ?>')
            },

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php $b++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
];
```

I see that the array named locationsFundet are populated, but the array named locationsTabt are not. This is the result:

```
var locationsFundet = [{
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(56.69244163539978, 11.612548828125),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet1')
}, {
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(55.20395325785898, 8.953857421875),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet2')
}, {
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(55.66519318443606, 10.601806640625),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet3')
}, {
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(56.292156685076456, 8.162841796875),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet4')
}, {
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(55.329535012504195, 12.457809448242188),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet5')
}, {
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(56.85375917920851, 10.267839431762695),
    info: document.getElementById('itemFundet6')
}, ];
var locationsTabt = [];
```

I am not necessarily looking for a complete answer from someone, although that would be nice. I am at least looking for a good idea about where to search for the issue.

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: This is great, Andreas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `json_encode` php function after a loop like the first one in your code.

I did not test the code, but it should look something like this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$b = 1;

$locationsFundet = array();
$locationsTabt = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

  $terms = get_the_terms($loop->ID, 'observationcat');

  foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    if ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 112)) :

      $locationsFundet[] = array('latlng' => 'new google.maps.LatLng'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true).')', 'info' => 'document.getElementById("itemFundet'.$i.'")' );

      $i++;

    elseif ((get_post_meta($loop->ID, '_location', true) !== '') && (($term->term_id) == 113)) :

      $locationsTabt[] = array('latlng' => 'new google.maps.LatLng'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true).')', 'info' => 'document.getElementById("itemTabt'.$b.'")' );

      $b++;

    endif;

  }

endwhile;

//Here you have the two javascript arrays:
echo 'var locationsFundet = '.json_encode($locationsFundet).';';
echo 'var locationsTabt = '.json_encode($locationsTabt).';';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@R3nPi2 and @Andreas this is great. Using json_encode() is the definitely the way. I was not aware about this method. Thanks

I managed to implement json_encode() and populate both arrays with the proper data. 
However, the format of the data within the array is required by my javascript to look as following:

```
var locationsFundet = [
                       {
                        latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(56.613931480691875,8.4210205078125),
                        info : document.getElementById('itemFundet1')   
                       },
```

The problem is that js_code populates the array the following way (Notice the colons and quotation marks):

```
var fundet = [
              {
               "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(56.43820369358164,10.997314453125)",
               "info":"document.getElementById(itemFundet1)"
              },

              {
               "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(55.20395325785898,15.084228515625)",
               "info":"document.getElementById(itemFundet2)"
              },

              {
               "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(57.314657355733274,11.195068359375)",
               "info":"document.getElementById(itemFundet3)"
              },

              {
               "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(56.85375917920851,10.267839431762695)",
               "info":"document.getElementById(itemFundet4)"
              }
];

var tabt = [
            {
             "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(56.613931480691875,8.4210205078125)",
             "info":"document.getElementById(itemTabt1)"
            },

            {
             "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(55.42901345240742,8.382568359375)",
             "info":"document.getElementById(itemTabt2)"
            },

            {
             "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(54.73730756865753,10.777587890625)",
             "info":"document.getElementById(itemTabt3)"
            },

            {
             "latlng:":"new google.maps.LatLng(55.329535012504195,12.457809448242188)",
             "info":"document.getElementById(itemTabt4)"
            }
];
```

Anybody got a method on how to make json_encode method populate the array with the format I need.

The javascript using the array looks as following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locationsFundet.length; i++) 
{  

    var markerFundet = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: locationsFundet[i].latlng,
        icon: fundetMarkerImg,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerFundet, 'click', (function(markerFundet, i) 
    {
        return function() 
        {
            infowindow.setContent(locationsFundet[i].info);
            infowindow.open(map, markerFundet);
        }
    })(markerFundet, i));
}

for (var b = 0; b < locationsTabt.length; b++) 
{  

    var markerTabt = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: locationsTabt[b].latlng,
        icon: fundetMarkerImg,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerTabt, 'click', (function(markerTabt, b) 
    {
        return function() 
        {
            infowindow.setContent(locationsTabt[b].info);
            infowindow.open(map, markerTabt);
        }
    })(markerTabt, b));
}
```

Comment: For the simple quotes sorrounding 'itemFundet1' you can change the array creation like this: `$locationsFundet[] = array('latlng' => 'new google.maps.LatLng'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true).')', 'info' => 'document.getElementById(\'itemFundet'.$i.'\')' );`
And to strip quotes from your json_encode you can use str_replace like this: `str_replace('"','',json_encode($locationsFundet))`
Hope it helps.
Refs: http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much R3nPi2!

With your help I managed to replace the unwanted symbols and characters.

This was my solution:

```
var fundetReplaced = <?php echo str_replace('"','', json_encode($locationFundet)); ?>
var tabtReplaced = <?php echo str_replace('"','', json_encode($locationTabt)); ?>
```

The result looks as following:

```
var fundetReplaced = [
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(56.43820369358164,10.997314453125),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemFundet1')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(55.20395325785898,15.084228515625),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemFundet2')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(57.314657355733274,11.195068359375),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemFundet3')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(56.85375917920851,10.267839431762695),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemFundet4')}];
var tabtReplaced = [
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(56.613931480691875,8.4210205078125),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemTabt1')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(55.42901345240742,8.382568359375),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemTabt2')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(54.73730756865753,10.777587890625),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemTabt3')},
                      {latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(55.329535012504195,12.457809448242188),
                       info:document.getElementById('itemTabt4')}];
```